# camel completionSize with completionTimeout not working correctly in JUnit

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a file like this

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
```

And a route like that:

```
.from("direct:start")
.split().tokenize("\r\n").streaming()
.process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Splitter:" +
            exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
    }
})
.aggregate(constant(true), new MyAggregationStrategy())
.completionSize(3).completionTimeout(10000)
.process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        int size = exchange.getIn().getBody(Set.class).size();
        System.out.println("Processor, Set size:" + size);
    }
})
.to("mock:end")
```

MyAggregationStrategy creates a Set with 3 items. This works well for the first 6 lines, I get an output like this:

```
Splitter:line 1
Splitter:line 2
Splitter:line 3
...
Processor, Set size:3
...
Splitter:line 4
Splitter:line 5
Splitter:line 6
...
Processor, Set size:3
...
Splitter:line 7
Splitter:line 8
```

Although line 7 and line 8 are aggregated in the oldExchange in MyAggregationStrategy the Processor defined afterwards is never called for them. Also the completionTimeout is not working. The Code terminates immediately and does not wait for 10 seconds for the not existing line 9.

Any idea? I thought this is the recommended way dealing with remaining lines that don't satisfy the completionSize?

Since we are bound to Java 6 we use camel version 2.13.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer!

The problem occured in JUnit only cause `finish.assertIsSatisfied()` is executed immediately and does not wait for the timeout given in `completionTimeout`.

Using `finish.assertIsSatisfied(long timeoutForEmptyEndpoints)`
 with a value higher than given in `completionTimeout` solved my Problem

Comment: Could you accept the answer so that the question is not listed as unanswered? Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to but the system says "You can accept your own answer in 21 hours".

Comment: Ah, the 48h wait period must still be in place. Damn, sorry.